# Big O Notation for a For-Loop

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, big-o, notation

How do I find the Big O Notation for this for-loop line of code

`for (int j = 0; pow(j,2) < n; j++) ?`

Does anyone know?

I have read a little on Big O Notation and it’s a very confusing topic to understand. I know that usually for-loop like this one → `for (int n = 0; n < 20; ++n)`, have a Big O notation of **O(1)**, as input increases by 13 so does its output, with linear complexity. Is that the same situation as above?

Comment: for loops usually have **O(n)**, not **O(1)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    doSomething(i);
}
```

iterates *n* times, so if `doSomething` has O(1) running time, then the loop as a whole has O(*n*) running time.

Similarly, a loop like this:

```
for (int j = 0; pow(j, 2) < n; j++) {
    doSomething(j);
}
```

iterates ⌈√*n*⌉ times, so if `doSomething` has O(1) running time, then the loop as a whole has O(√*n*) running time.

By the way, note that although `pow(j, 2)` is O(1) running time — so it doesn't affect your loop's asymptotic complexity — it's nonetheless pretty slow, because it involves logarithms and exponentiation. For most purposes, I'd recommend this instead:

```
for (int j = 0; j * j < n; j++) {
    doSomething(j);
}
```

or perhaps this:

```
for (int j = 0; 1.0 * j * j < n; j++) {
    doSomething(j);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense now.